# Unable to seat Eaton CH breakers side-by-side in my Eaton CH panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

This is probably an embarrassing newbie mistake, but I've really been scratching my head over this. I have an Eaton subpanel that states it accepts Eaton type CH, CHT, or CH3 branch breakers. However, when I try to seat two CH breakers side by side, the breaker on one side unseats the breaker on the other. They don't both seem to fit. I've temporarily gotten around this by installing breakers only on one side of the panel, but I would love to know what the problem is and also make sure I am using compatible breakers.

I'm having the issue with regular Eaton CH breakers and also Eaton CH AFCI/GFCI combination breakers (not the plug-on-neutral kind).

Here are images of the subpanel label, inside the subpanel, and also a gif of me trying to seat the breakers side by side:

[image: subpanel label]
[image: subpanel]
[image: gif of seating Eaton CH breakers side by side]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: BTW: I take it you've removed the green bonding screw on the right side of the panel, considering this is a subpanel fed with a 4-wire feeder?

Comment: I'd speculate that you may not have the outer edge seated properly, so the breakers are "tilted in to the center" a bit too much, based on your video. I don't have this type of panel so that's just speculation from observation, not  certainty. But that's what it looks like.

Comment: I agree, the tail of at least the right side breaker is not hooked in properly, they shouldn't interfere with each other like that... I use mainly CH...

Comment: Thanks, all. I just went out and tried pushing both in at the same time, and after a few attempts was able to seat them securely. If one of you wants to leave your comment as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's hard to tell in that picture, but the bonding screw is not tightened in. Is it necessary that it be completely removed?

Comment: One practice is to remove it completely but drop it in the bottom of the panel, as a visual remonder that it's not there without losing it if the function of the panel ever changed. If it's sitting in the bottom it can't fall aywhere that would cause a problem. Not sure what code thinks of that, my (former) electricain seems to have had a masters license in 3 states and a near-total disregard for code to go with them...

Comment: You have a single black wire exiting the bottom of the panel through a hole without any protection. I believe that's a violation, though since both TPE and @Harper-ReinstateMonica have looked at this and not noticed, maybe it's not.

Comment: @freeman pretend the wire is bare.  It's the grounding electrode :)  That said, it is a different violation if it's #6 or smaller, since native colors are required for neutrals and grounds.

Comment: Yes of course you  must remove the bonding screw, it's not an adjustment!  If it's still hanging on by a thread, those threads are in the panel chassis so it's still bonded.  If it's floating, then it's free to fall out itself or slide back in and touch chassis.   You know, NEC 110.3(B) requires you to install according to instructions and labeling, which kinda implies you must read them :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I saw the green grounding wire connected to the ground bus, so ass-u-med that this was something else. I do see, now, that there is a black wire connected to the top screw on that bus. Guess I didn't put 1 and 1 together to come up with 10...

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica and FreeMan.To clarify, a licensed electrician installed this sub-panel (not me), and it already passed inspection, but it sounds like removing the screw is the way to go, so I will go ahead and do that!

Comment: Also, to clarify further, the screw is threaded into a big plastic piece, not the panel chasis, and the label that can be seen to the right of the screw only says "when required to bond ground to neutral, thread screw into case". It doesn't explicitly say to remove the screw if not bonding. Confusing to a non-electrician like myself. Either way, I'll remove!

Comment: @stephen.hanson Hmm well, instructions and labeling override both us and NEC.  However I still say "remove" because it's too prone to being misunderstood.  It won't go anywhere in the bottom of the panel.  Also, I am superstitious about relying on ground screws as grounding paths; I've seen screws vaporize from a bolted fault, appear to be present and actually be gone.  I prefer a nice heavy #4 copper ground wire, also you can put a clamp meter around that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try snapping them both in at the same time. I have the same breakers with a Cutler Hammer panel and the breakers need to be seated correctly on the back bar before they will snap into place..